# Why is the code not working? Neither client.on("ready") is working nor is client.on("messageCreate")

Tags: javascript, discord.js

this is the code, from most sources that I have seen, this should work

this is the entire file

```
const Discord = require("discord.js")

const TOKEN = ""

const client = new Discord.Client({
    intents: [
        "GUILDS",
        "GUILD_MESSAGES"
    ]
})

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log('Logged in as  ${client.user.tag}')
})

client.on("messageCreate", (message) => {
    if (message.content == "hi") {
        message.reply("Hello")
    }
})

client.login(TOKEN)
```

Comment: Can you add your complete `index.js` file as that would be more helpful?

Comment: If you have an error, you can share it too.

Answer (score 0):

Your intents are set incorrectly...

try this:

```js
intents: [
    Discord.Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Discord.Intents.FALGS.GUILD_MESSAGES
]
```

About **messageCreate**:

> If you need your bot to receive messages ( MESSAGE_CREATE - "messageCreate" in discord. js), you need the **GUILD_MESSAGES** intent. Done so like this: `Discord.Intents.FALGS.GUILD_MESSAGES`

[More on Intent Privileges](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/intents.html#the-intents-bitfield)